# Design Patterns for simplest, easiest to use website Feedback/Contact us form?

Tags: gui-design, design-patterns, user-feedback

I'm looking for some canonical examples of Feedback forms. (Sort of Best Practice kind of thing).

Goal is to make this as easy to use and gather only enough info to respond to the user.

I've looked in the Yahoo Design Patterns but no luck.

Comment: Asking for 'some examples of x' means you're question is too broad, as by definition there is no correct answer. Can you explain your specific situation and what it is you're trying to achieve and we can then solve that specific issue for you. But just asking for examples of something isn't really suited to a Q&A site I'm afraid.

Comment: Johns, did I adequately address your concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `canonical` translates to `rule` then I vouch for KISS (Keep It Simple Silly)

I think the simpler you can make it then the better experience your user will have:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7zybL.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I despise feedback forms which ask things like:

- Department
- Type of feedback
- Software name
- Software version
- Your OS

and then have the nerve to make 6/5 of them required fields.

Are you looking for user convenience or will this feedback get sent through a slew of processes which figure the appropriate destination of the feedback?

Comment: The final S in KISS should not be made kid friendly. It's the most important letter in the acronym! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different formats that one can take to give a customer feedback form, but the format may not be the most important part. Often times it is how you project the form to the user, what questions you ask and how quickly it can be completed. I found a site that has a bunch of canonical examples (if I truly understand canonical :P) [Guidelines for Feedback Forms](http://www.customersure.com/blog/customer-feedback-forms/). It's a good read if your trying to further your understanding on how to create an effective feedback form. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a new type of feedback form where the users can both rank categories that they think are most important to them (features, look and feel, help, etc) as well as provide a rating for each category. So just think of it as a combination of a list that you can change the order of, and each list item is a slider bar or input that allows users to enter the rating level.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, the feedback form design that is frequently used by the user is a good design. In this sense, Amazon.com's feedback form is the best I've ever seen. Amazon provides two possibilities for feedback: general feedback and order-specific feedback. For the former, you can choose the reason of contact from a list of common reasons. For the latter, relevant information about the order will be sent with your feedback automatically. It's a nice design from the customer's point of view.